# Accessing properties of SVGs made using D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am making a simple Bar Chart in d3 and would like to plot bars for the height of a few dogs and would like a small dot above the bars to indicate the weight. The following code works well and creates the  bars needed and positioned in place.

```
const svg = d3.select('.chartArea').append('svg')
    .attr('height' , 500)
    .attr('width' , 600); 

const heightBars = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(dogs)

heightBars.enter().append('rect')
    .attr('width' , 40)
    .attr('height' , (d) => y(d.height))
    .attr('y' , (d) => 500- y(d.height) )
    .attr('x',  (d,i) => (60*i))
    .attr('fill' , (d) => d.color)
    .attr('id', (d) => d.name)
```

I would like to use to cooridinates of the bars I have already made to make the circles, but am finding it hard to access the attributes of the 6 rectangles. As you can see I have given them all ID's but when trying to check and run the line:

```
console.log(d3.select('#labrador').attr('y'))
```

I get the error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

How can I access properties of svgs I made using d3?

Thanks :)

**Edit**

I managed to plumb together the following that works but is very ugly:

```
weightDots.enter().append('circle')
.attr('cx' , (d) => parseInt(d3.select('.'+ d.name).attr('x')) +20  )
.attr('cy' ,  (d) =>  400-yW(d.weight) )
.attr('r' , 10)
.attr('fill' , (d) => d.color)
```

Comment: You have one data array for both height and weight? Or two, one for each?

Comment: one data object for both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another enter append using the same data e.g something like this. (I didn't add colours or ids, but the first section is your code)

```js
dogs=[
{
  height: 54,
  weight: 3,
},
{
  height: 34,
  weight: 3
},
{
  height: 84,
  weight: 3
}
]

const svg = d3.select('.chartArea').append('svg')
    .attr('height' , 500)
    .attr('width' , 600); 

const heightBars = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(dogs)

heightBars.enter().append('rect')
    .attr('width' , 40)
    .attr('height' , (d) => d.height)
    .attr('y' , (d) => 500 - d.height)
    .attr('x',  (d,i) => (60*i))
    
svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(dogs)
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr('cy', d => 475 - d.height)
  .attr('cx', (d,i) => 60*i + 20) // 1/2 bar width offset
  .attr('r', 10)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="chartArea"></div>
```